# Inverse Laplace Transformation of a heaviside function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I'm working through an example of an inverse laplace transformation:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}[\frac{e^{-3s}}{s+1}] = u_3(t)e^{-(t-3)}$$

I am having trouble seeing how this works. I know that:

$\mathscr{L}^{-1}[Y(s-a)]=e^{at}y(t)$ and that $\mathscr{L}[u_a(t)]=\frac{e^{-as}}{s}$ so $\mathscr{L}[u_a(t-a)]=\frac{e^{-a(s-a)}}{s-a}$.

I can't get the problem to look quite like the shifted $Y(s-a)$ when I let $a=-1$, but I am not sure how else to proceed as I need that term in the denominator:

$$Y(s-1)=\frac{e^{-(-1)(s-(-1))}}{s-(-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The exponential term $e^{-3s}$ merely transforms in the time-domain as a time shift of $3$, while the term $\frac{1}{s+1}$ transforms into a decaying exponential function.

Let's see this as follows.

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(t-3)}u(t-3) e^{-st}dt=e^3 \int_3^{\infty} e^{-(s+1)t}dt=\frac{e^{-3s}}{s+1}$$

So, if the Laplace transform of $e^{-(t-3)}u(t-3)$ is $\frac{e^{-3s}}{s+1}$, then the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-3s}}{s+1}$ must be $e^{-(t-3)}u(t-3)$.

Comment: Sure this makes perfect sense, I'm having trouble going the other direction.

Comment: One may either use the integral form of tve inverse transform or learn basic transform pairs along with transform rules.  Here, the rule is that $e^{as}$ transforms into a time shift.